# How can i right click in a WPF Popup without it losing focus

Tags: wpf, textbox, popup, focus

I have a text box that has spell check enabled. It is inside a popup. This enables me to edit multi line text in a datagrid, when the text is being edited the text box it is in grows over the top of the grid instead of resizing the height of the row.

The problem is that when the red squiggly lines appear to indicate a spelling mistake i cant right click on them, because when i do the popup closes.

I have tried Popup.StaysOpen but to no avail. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this outside the context of the `DataGrid`? I have a hunch that it is most likely the `DataGrid` detecting that focus has been lost and is automatically applying your edits, changing the template for the cell and thus closing your `Popup`.